# Compare two CSV files in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have to write vbscript to compare two csv files,

The both csv files contains the following data format,
File1.csv

```
DBNane UserGroup Path                 Access
DB_1    Dev_II   DB/Source/Projects   Read/Write
DB_2    Test_I   DB/Source/Doc        Read
```

File2.csv

```
DBNane UserGroup Path                 Access
DB_1    Dev_II   DB/Source/Projects   Read
DB_2    Test_I   DB/Source/Doc        Read
```

I need to compare these files, the output format is like,

File3.csv

```
DBNane UserGroup Path                 Access
DB_1    Dev_II   DB/Source/Projects   Read/Write
```

I'm new to the vbscript. Any sample script to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6192244/603855 for an SQL strategy to solve problems like this; you should at least hint at the reason for *not* choosing the data from file2.csv.

Comment: Is it required to be VBScript? It would be pretty easy with PowerShell. You could also look at using something like WinMerge if it doesn't have to be automated.

Comment: @alroc can u plz provide me the example code to compare two excel files using powershell

Comment: Excel files, or CSV files? It's 2 completely different solutions.

Comment: @user1553605 You need to explain *why* `File3.csv` has the content that it does. That are your rules/criteria?

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell you could get differing lines from 2 text files like this:

```
$f1 = Get-Content 'C.\path\to\file1.csv'
$f2 = Get-Content 'C.\path\to\file2.csv'

Compare-Object $f1 $f2
```

If you only need to show what's different in the first file (`$f1`), you could filter the result like this:

```
Compare-Object $f1 $f2 | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | % { $_.InputObject }
```

Comment: Could you possibly throw in a filter to restrict the output of Compare-Object to the desired result?

Comment: Done. However, this is merely an example. I agree with alroc that the OP needs to clarify what output he expects.

Comment: Thanks for the impressive demo of the power of Powershell.