# VB Script - Compare two csv files and create a third based on results

Tags: vbscript

Ive been working on a small vbscript project and would like some advice on the next stage of the coding. Im not sure what is the best method going forward although i assume i will have to use dynamic arrays and some form of looping.

The first stage queries a SQL database and exports the output to a delimited file. Lets call this ListA.csv. This consist of 2 columns; File,Modified Date (e.g. MyFile.doc,17/01/2014 12:00:45). 1 record per line. Potentially it may have hundreds of entries.

The second stage does a similar job but queries a local file structure for similar info. the only exception is that it also include an extra column for the path to file. Lets call this ListB.csv. (e.g. MyFile.doc,17/01/2014 13:00:45,C:\Myfolder\Myfile.doc). again this is one record per line.

The next job which is where i need help is to compare the entries in file B, to those in File A and create a third file list (ListC.csv) based on three tests.
1. Filename listed on ListB is not found on ListA
2. Filename listed on ListB is found on ListA but is older than ListA version.
3. Filename listed on ListB is found on ListA but ListA modified date is less than 14 days (from today).

I wont bore you with the reason i am doing this apart from the idea it is part of a housekeeping solution i am working on. A point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

The final stage is to delete or archive but i have this in hand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this link. [Find if listA contains any elements not in listB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524681/linq-compare-two-lists) it essentially was what I was going to suggest in the first place. I am going to assume you are reading both of these files at some point. My suggestion is at time of reading to create IEnumerable. This will give you much better control. 
The Except function is LINQ is awesome.

Comment: That has nothing to do with VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved by using SQL. So either import your second file into your DBMS or connect to a folder containing both your files via ADO/Text driver. Then create the suitable queries (keywords: INSERT/SELECT INTO, (LEFT) JOIN).

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192244/603855).